# Actionscript 1 not in Flash IDE anymore

Tags: actionscript-1

How come the updated version of Flash Professional doesn't have an option for an actionscript-1 `fla`?  Is actionscript-1 that unpopular, and how much has really changed in the evolution of as1 to as2?

Comment: Because it's going to be 10 years obsolete next year?

Comment: Contrary to my current observations, I would think that this question would attract angry users, thwarting your tumbleweed badge attempt.  But I guess nobody's noticing this... hmm.  Is it technically against the rules to ask sub-par questions on purpose?

Comment: @SimonT Well I did kind of want to know the answer, and now I know that it's been obsolete....